# Importing vendor JS file into Ember-CLI route file

Tags: javascript, ember.js, bower, ember-cli

I have an Ember CLI project, and one of my routes starts like:

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import Activity from '../models/activity';

var ACCESS_KEY = gOptions.access_key;

export default Ember.Route.extend({
...
```

I have a file `vendor/local_config.js` that contains **machine-specific** information, and is in the `.gitignore` to be omitted from the repository. It contains:

```
var gOptions = {
    access_key: 'abcde'
};
```

In my `ember-cli-build.js` file, I have imported this file like so:

```
app.import('vendor/local_config.js');
```

*Running* this application, everything works perfectly. The `gOptions` is universally available.

However, **JSHint complains**:

```
routes/activities.js: line 4, col 25, 'gOptions' is not defined.
```

I'm very new to Ember - what is the preferred method for updating my route to ensure that the vendor-provided classes are properly resolved/detected when JSHint is examining my routes/models?

**Or:** Is there a superior/Ember-like way of providing locally-defined environment variables, that should *not* be shared to a team?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're importing a global library, you just need to add the library to your JSHint configuration. From the [Ember-CLI documentation](http://www.ember-cli.com/user-guide/#standard-non-amd-asset):

> Note: Don’t forget to make JSHint happy by adding a /* global MY_GLOBAL */ to your module, or by defining it within the predefs section of your .jshintrc file.

So just open up your `.jshintrc` file and add `gOptions` to the `predefs` array.